# Passing scaled Data to a .h5 model in python/flask

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, model

I have a .h5 model that works in Colab and I can pass data to it and receive an output however when I put the model into a python/flask environment I am  having difficulty passing scaled data from the html to the model. How do I scale this new input data and pass it to the model.
The model was built using .csv data.

I have tried using MinMaxScaler/MinMaxScaler() however this asks for the training data which would be impractical every time the app runs.